# Managing 3 Shopify Stores with Github

Tags: github, shopify

Let me tell you my story I have 3 Shopify Stores, 3 different envs (dev, test, prod) which on result I got 3 different variables (endpoint_apis, etc.).

I try to manage them on a single GitHub repository, using .git-ignore for schema-settings (this's the main file that contains env-vars).
It didn't work as expected when I try to PR and merge from a child branch to main ones.

Ex:
main,test,dev

Create a branch: “Feat1” that comes from dev, finished it need a PR to test. So here it's where everything explodes. When trying to merge.

If someone has any suggestion, would be really appreciated
Thanks